# draw in Canvas with bufferStrategy

Tags: java, canvas, jframe

I have a code working that shows the evolution of a virtual earth.
I'm using a JFrame and a bufferedStrategy to draw this world.

I would like to add either on top of the world drawn either next to it, two buttons that can affect the map.

Here is my try :

```
public class Window extends JFrame{

private BufferStrategy bs;
private Planete plan;
private Canvas canvasDroite = new Canvas();
private JPanel panelGauche = new JPanel();
final JButton btn = new JButton("Test");
final JButton btn2 = new JButton("Test 2");

public Window(String name, Planete p){
this.setTitle(name);                    
canvasDroite.setSize(new Dimension(Constante.longueur ,Constante.largeur));                 
this.setSize(1600,900);
this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);           
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
this.setResizable(false);               
this.setVisible(true);                      
//this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
canvasDroite.createBufferStrategy(3);               
bs = canvasDroite.getBufferStrategy();              
frameOrganize();
plan = p;

}

public void frameOrganize(){
    //panelGauche.add(btn);
    //panelGauche.add(btn2);
    this.add(canvasDroite);
    //this.add("West",panelGauche);
}

public void draw()
{
Graphics2D g = null; //pointeur de l'outil de dessin
do{
    try{
    g = (Graphics2D)bs.getDrawGraphics();
    if(plan != null)
        plan.draw(g);
    }
    finally
    {
        g.dispose(); 
    }
    bs.show(); 
} while (bs.contentsLost()); 
}

}
```

When there is only the frame everything work

I tried to create the bufferedStrategie in a JPanel but it doesn't work, I only use g.drawLine() ( when I do plan.draw(g)) to change the map so I tried to drop the bufferStrategy and draw directly into the JPanel but I didn't succeed

And my try with the Canvas doesn't work either, the window appear but nothing is drawn.

I also tried to use paint() and repaint() for Canvas and JPanel.

PS : I looked many post but I've never seen when is used the paint(Graphics g) method for a JPanel to start the painting, that's why I use bufferstrategy, It's easier in my point of view.

Comment: Based on your code, nothing is calling `draw`, so, nothing will be painted.  Understand the difference between overriding something like `paintComponent` and using `BufferStrategy` - they are two different approaches, which are not generally compatible with each other.  Swing uses a passive rendering engine (updating as needed), where as `BufferStrategy` is completely under your control - you can decide when and how often it should be painted.  You won't be able to use Swing components on the `Canvas` while using `BufferStrategy` - the painting routines are incompatiable

Comment: Having said that, you can add an additional container (`JPanel`) to the frame which can contain the buttons

Comment: I didn't put all the code, I call `draw` in the main, but you are right I don't understand the difeerences between using `paintComponent` and `BufferStrategy`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I founed the solution ! Here is my code if anyone need it, my mystake was that I didn't understand how use the paintComponent of a JPanel;

```
public class Window extends JFrame{

    private BufferStrategy bs;
    private Planete plan;
    private JPanel panelDroite = new JPanel();
    private JPanel panelGauche = new JPanel();
    final JButton btn = new JButton("yolo");
    final JButton btn2 = new JButton("yolo 2");

    public Window(String name, Planete p){
    this.setTitle(name);                    //titre de fenetre
    panelDroite.setSize(new Dimension(Constante.longueur ,Constante.largeur));              //change la taille
    this.setSize(1600,900);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);           //place au centre
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    //quitte avec la croix
    this.setResizable(false);               //empeche resize
    organisageFenetre();

    this.setVisible(true);                  //rend visible

    //this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    plan = p;

    }

    //Créer un update

    public void organisageFenetre(){
        //panelGauche.add(btn);
        //panelGauche.add(btn2);
        this.add(panelDroite);
        //this.add("West",panelGauche);
    }

    public void paintComponent()
    {
    //dessine toute la fenetre
    Graphics g = null; //pointeur de l'outil de dessin
        try{
        g = (Graphics)panelDroite.getGraphics(); //recupere l'outil de dessin de la fenetre de dessin
        if(plan != null)
            plan.draw(g);
        }
        finally
        {
            panelDroite.repaint();
            g.dispose(); //termine l'utilisation de l'outil de dessin
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That's not a solution I would recommend to anyone - never call `getGraphics`, it's a temporary snapshot of the last paint cycle, the next paint cycle will remove anything painted to it. You should also not be calling `dispose` on a context you didn't create